# Clojure translate from Java

Tags: clojure

I'm starting to learn Clojure and have decided that doing some projects on HackerRank is a good way to do that. What I'm finding is that my Clojure solutions are horribly slow. I'm assuming that's because I'm still thinking imperatively or just don't know enough about how Clojure operates. The latest problem I wrote solutions for was Down To Zero II. Here's my Java code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Solution {
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 1000000;
    private static final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static int[] precompute() {
        int[] values = new int[MAX_NUMBER];

        values[0] = 0;
        values[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < MAX_NUMBER; i += 1) {
            if ((values[i] == 0) || (values[i] > (values[i - 1] + 1))) {
                values[i] = (values[i - 1] + 1);
            }

            for (int j = 1; j <= i && (i * j) < MAX_NUMBER; j += 1) {
                int mult = i * j;

                if ((values[mult] == 0) || (values[mult] > (values[i] + 1))) {
                    values[mult] = values[i] + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return values;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int numQueries = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        int[] values = Solution.precompute();

        for (int loop = 0; loop < numQueries; loop += 1) {
            int query = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            System.out.println(values[query]);
        }
    }
}
```

My Clojure implementation is

```
(def MAX-NUMBER 1000000)

(defn set-i [out i]
(cond
    (= 0 i) (assoc out i 0)
    (= 1 i) (assoc out i 1)
    (or (= 0 (out i))
        (> (out i) (inc (out (dec i)))))
    (assoc out i (inc (out (dec i))))
    :else out))

(defn set-j [out i j]
(let [mult (* i j)]
    (if (or (= 0 (out mult)) (> (out mult) (inc (out i))))
    (assoc out mult (inc (out i)))
    out)))

;--------------------------------------------------
; Precompute the values for all possible inputs
;--------------------------------------------------
(defn precompute []
(loop [i 0 out (vec (repeat MAX-NUMBER 0))]

    (if (< i MAX-NUMBER)
    (recur (inc i) (loop [j 1 new-out (set-i out i)]
                    (if (and (<= j i) (< (* i j) MAX-NUMBER))
                        (recur (inc j) (set-j new-out i j))
                        new-out)))
    out)))

;--------------------------------------------------
; Read the number of queries
;--------------------------------------------------
(def num-queries (Integer/parseInt (read-line)))

;--------------------------------------------------
; Precompute the solutions
;--------------------------------------------------
(def values (precompute))

;--------------------------------------------------
; Read and process each query
;--------------------------------------------------
(loop [iter 0]
(if (< iter num-queries)
    (do
    (println (values (Integer/parseInt (read-line))))
    (recur (inc iter)))))
```

The Java code runs in about 1/10 of a second on my machine, while the Clojure code takes close to 2 seconds. Since it's the same machine, with the same JVM, it means I'm doing something wrong in Clojure.

How do people go about trying to translate this type of code? What are the gotchas that are causing it to be so much slower?

Comment: how are you running your code? are you using `lein`, passing the .clj file to `clojure` or some other way?

Comment: I just wanted to add: I haven't looked at the problem statement, but you are using `loop/recur` for iteration. Clojure prefers `for`, `reduce` and `map`. There are many more things like type hints if you look for clojure performance tips.

Comment: `(vec (repeat 1e6 0))` is very expensive. It's creating a million element vector full of 0s. That takes a full second alone on my underclocked phone. `(int-array 1e6 0)` on the other hand takes like 14 milliseconds. If you're actually needing to store that much data, arrays may be a better choice. I can't otherwise see anything overly inefficient in your code though. I will say though, if you post it on Code Review, I'd do a review of it tomorrow if you like. It looks like there's a few places where I can make suggestions.

Comment: From some of the things I've read, I got the impression loop/recur performs better than reduce.  It's basically a nested loop that sets A[i] and then for j <= i sets A[i * j] based on that.

Comment: It seemed like map should be the way to go, but I couldn't see how to have map set multiple values or how to chain it so that the resulting vector had the right entries.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the input data you're using for this that you can share? Is it just the 2 3 4 example code from the problem description?

Comment: The 2 3 4 input works. precompute generates a lookup table that is used, so the input doesn't have much effect on it. I'm starting to think it might not be anything horribly wrong with my code, but more an inherent issue with Clojure. I've been trying some other simple programs like this and Clojure seems to be roughly 10x slower than Java. At least for things that do a ton of loops.

Comment: @Rich as others have noted loops are generally not how one does things in Clojure most of the time. Clojure code _is_ slower - there's a material performance hit for the runtime type interpretation - but you can also get around that if you care about speed by providing type hints to the compiler. If you're curious how I'd go about the problem (leaving aside the memoization/dynamic programming aspect of this), my code would look like this: https://gist.github.com/venantius/ff4ed7135c8a0802accd81bafe8c8313

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do some transformations to your code (which might be slightly outside of what you were originally asking)
and then address your more specific questions.

I know it's almost two years later, but after running across your question and spending way too much time fighting with
HackerRank and its time limits, I thought I would post an answer. Does achieving a solution within HR's environment and
time limits make us better Clojure programmers? I didn't learn the answer to that. But I'll share what I did learn.

I found a slightly slimmer version of your same algorithm. It still has two loops, but the update only happens once in
the inner loop, and many of the conditions are handled in a `min` function. Here is my adaptation of it:

```
(defn compute
  "Returns a vector of down-to-zero counts for all numbers from 0 to m."
  [m]
  (loop [i 2 out (vec (range (inc m)))]
    (if (<= i m)
      (recur (inc i)
             (loop [j 1 out out]
               (let [ij (* i j)]
                 (if (and (<= j i) (<= ij m))
                   (recur (inc j) 
                          (assoc out ij (min (out ij)               ;; current value
                                             (inc (out (dec ij)))   ;; steps from value just below
                                             (inc (out i)))))       ;; steps from a factor
                   out))))
      out)))
```

Notice we're still using loop/recur (twice), we're still using a vector to hold the output. But some differences:

1. We initialize `out` to incrementing integers. This is the worst case number of steps for every value, and once
   initialized, we don't have to test that a value equals 0 and we can skip indices 0 and 1 and start the outer loop at
   index 2. (We also fix a bug in your original and make sure `out` contains `MAX-NUMBER+1` values.)
2. All three tests happen inside a `min` function that encapsulates the original logic: a value will be
   updated only if it's a shorter number of steps from the number just below it, or from one of it's factors.
3. The tests are now simple enough that we don't need to break them out into separate functions.

This code (along with your original) is fast enough to pass *some* of the test cases in HR, but not all. Here are some
things to speed this up:

1. Use `int-array` instead of `vec`. This means we'll use `aset` instead of `assoc` and `aget` instead of calling `out`
   with an index. It also means that `loop/recur` isn't the best structure anymore (because we are no longer passing
   around new versions of an immutable vector, but actually mutating a `java.util.Array`); instead we'll use `doseq`.
2. Type hints. This alone makes a huge speed difference. When testing your code, include a form at the top `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` and you'll see where Clojure is having to do extra work to figure out what types it is
   dealing with.
3. Use custom I/O functions to read the input. HR's boilerplate I/O code is supposed to let you focus on solving the
   challenge and not worry about I/O, but it is basically garbage, and often the culprit behind your program timing out.

Below is a version that incorporates the tips above and runs fast enough to pass all test cases. I've included my custom
I/O approach that I've been using for all my HR challenges. One nice benefit of using `doseq` is we can include a
`:let` and a `:while` clause within the binding form, removing some of the indentation within the body of `doseq`. Also
notice a few strategically placed type hints that really speed up the program.

```
(ns down-to-zero-int-array)

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn compute
  "Returns a vector of down-to-zero counts for all numbers from 0 to m."
  ^ints [m]
  (let [out ^ints (int-array (inc m) (range (inc m)))]
    (doseq [i (range 2 (inc m)) j (range 1 (inc i)) :let [ij (* i j)] :while (<= ij m)]
      (aset out ij (min (aget out ij)
                        (inc (aget out (dec ij)))
                        (inc (aget out i)))))
    out))

(let [tokens ^java.io.StreamTokenizer 
      (doto (java.io.StreamTokenizer. (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))
        (.parseNumbers))]
  (defn next-int []
    "Read next integer from input. As fast as `read-line` for a single value, 
     and _much_ faster than `read-line`+`split` for multiple values on same line."
    (.nextToken tokens)
    (int (.-nval tokens))))

(def MAX 1000000)

(let [q (next-int)
      down-to-zero (compute MAX)]
  (doseq [n (repeatedly q next-int)]
    (println (aget down-to-zero n))))
```